# How to bring different values from results column into single row by value from other column sql

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

I have the following tables:

| Teammate ID | Teammate name | Team id | Teams |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amy | 11 | Sales |
| 1 | Amy | 12 | Support |
| 1 | Amy | 13 | Marketing |
| 2 | Peter | 12 | Support |
| 2 | Peter | 13 | Marketing |

And I want to group my results so the Teams column appears in one single row by Teammate Id or Teammate name as per below:

| Teammate ID | Teammate name | Team id | Teams |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Amy | 11, 12, 13 | Sales, Support, Marketing |
| 2 | Peter | 12, 13 | Support, Marketing |

Which function would be best/cleanest to use for this purpose? I tried subqueries, coalescing, some weird XML path thing but as a new SQL user I can't wrap my head around figuring this one out

My original query which gave me the results is;

```
   SELECT
    tm.teammate_id AS "Teammate ID",
    tm.name AS "Teammate name",
    
    itt.team_id AS "Team IDs",
    
    it.team AS "Teams"
    
    
FROM
    intercom_teammates AS tm

LEFT JOIN intercom_teammate_teams AS itt 
ON tm.teammate_id = itt.teammate_id

LEFT JOIN intercom_teams AS it 
ON tm.teammate_id = itt.teammate_id
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Will be different answers.)

Comment: On SQL Server you'd use GROUP BY + STRING_AGG() function. On MySQL accordingly GROUP BY + GROUP_CONCAT().

Comment: Thank you @RhythmWasaLurker - the version query returns "10.5.17-MariaDB-log". Does that help?

Comment: Then you aren't using SQL Server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simple group_concat would do the trick:

```
select it.TeammateID,
       group_concat( distinct it.Teammatename SEPARATOR ',') as Teammatename,
       group_concat( it.Teamid SEPARATOR ',') as Teamid,
       group_concat( it.Teams SEPARATOR ',') as Teams
from intercom_teammates it
group by it.TeammateID ;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/rU8-h8rX

*Note*. I used distinct on Teammatename, but I think it is excess and you can remove it if for every different TeammateID the Teammatename is unique.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    tm.teammate_id AS "Teammate ID",
    tm.name AS "Teammate name",
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT itt.team_id ORDER BY itt.team_id ASC) AS "Team IDs",
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT it.team ORDER BY it.team DESC) AS "Teams"
FROM intercom_teammates tm
LEFT JOIN intercom_teammate_teams itt ON tm.teammate_id = itt.teammate_id
LEFT JOIN intercom_teams it ON tm.teammate_id = it.teammate_id
GROUP BY tm.teammate_id, tm.name
```

**Note**: I've corrected your `JOIN` to `intercom_teams` changing `itt.teammate_id` to `it.teammate_id`; it was throwing off the result set.

**Result:**

```
| Teammate ID | Teammate name | Team IDs | Teams                    |
|-------------|---------------|----------|--------------------------|
| 1           | Amy           | 11,12,13 | Support,Sales,Marketing  |
| 2           | Peter         | 12,13    | Support,Marketing        |
```

*Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/YTFUpKBs).*